# Building an app for Gf's birthday - having trouble updating state in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

So I'm building out a Gardening app for my girlfriends birthday to help her keep track of her garden, and my deadline (lol) is fast approaching! Basic implementation for version 1 is almost complete, but I'm with getting the data I want to appear without refreshing the page. This is my first time using Redux / trying to implement user authentication, so I'm probably just being dumb, BUT:

Essentially, the way the app is currently built, I get a bunch of data about the plants in the garden from state:

```
const plants = useSelector(state => state.plant.plants);
```

Then inside of my useEffect hooks, after the user has been authenticated, I filter through the list of plants to create a new list, with only the plants that were added by that specific user:

```
useEffect(() => {
dispatch(getPlants()); }, [dispatch]);
useEffect(() => { if (user && isAuthenticated) { const usersGarden = plants.filter(plant => plant.addedBy._id === user._id) setGarden(usersGarden) } }, [user, isAuthenticated, plants])
```

This new, user specific list of plants is supposed to be stored in state (garden and setGarden), and it is... the problem is that it won't appear until I've refreshed the page once.

This is what happens, in order:

While logged out:- My "state" console.log immediately shows data- The "plants" console.log (which is the useSelector hook that gets plants from state) eventually gets the plants, though it's logged as empty twice (I'm also not sure why these get logged so many times)- Garden is empty

Console/UI image: https://ibb.co/nrSPf0N

2. After logging in:- State and plants console logs have data- Garden console.log still doesn't have the filtered list of the user's plants :((((((((

Console/UI image: https://ibb.co/VYP6BZF

1. After logging in and refreshing the page once:-garden suddenly has the data that I want, and everything magically appears (If only I didn't have to refresh)

Console/UI image: https://ibb.co/6gH5z12

What am I doing wrong? =/

Full code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container, Card, CardBody, CardTitle, Button, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getPlants, deletePlant } from '../actions/plantActions';
import PlantModal from './PlantModal';
import PlantDetailModal from './PlantDetailModal';


export const Garden = () => {
  const plants = useSelector(state => state.plant.plants);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.auth);
  const { user, isAuthenticated } = auth;
  const [garden, setGarden] = useState([])

  console.log('state', useSelector(state => state))
  console.log('plants', plants)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPlants());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user && isAuthenticated) {
      const usersGarden = plants.filter(plant => plant.addedBy._id === user._id)
      setGarden(usersGarden)
    }
  }, [user, isAuthenticated, plants])

  console.log('garden', garden)


  if (user && isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col xs="auto" className="mt-1">
            <h1 style={{ fontSize: "2.5rem", color: "#ffffb5" }}>{user ? user.name : null}'s Garden</h1>
          </Col>
          <Col className="py-2 text-right">
            <PlantModal />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Container fluid style={{ border: "3px solid #ffffb5", backgroundColor: "#99b898", borderRadius: "4px" }}>
          <Row>
            {garden.map(({ _id, name, description, growingZone, grownFromSeed, heirloom, idealTemp, imageURL, plantingDate, scientificName, seedDepth, soilType, spacing, sproutsIn, sunlight, timeToHarvest, watering }) => (
              <Col key={_id} className="my-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <Card className="text-center" body style={{ width: "275px", maxWidth: "275px" }}>
                  <Row className="text-right" style={{ marginTop: "-12px" }}>
                    <Col>
                      {isAuthenticated ? (
                        <Button
                          close
                          onClick={() => {
                            dispatch(deletePlant(_id));
                          }}
                        >
                        </Button>
                      ) : null}
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>
                      <CardTitle>
                        <h4>{name}</h4>
                        <hr />
                        <h6 className="font-italic text-muted">{scientificName}</h6>
                      </CardTitle>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <CardBody className="p-0">
                    {<img className="rounded mt-3 mb-0 p-0" style={{ width: "230px", maxWidth: "230px" }} src={imageURL} alt="plant"></img> || <div className="rounded mb-4" style={{ width: "200px", height: "100px", backgroundColor: "seagreen" }}></div>}
                    <PlantDetailModal 
                        name={name} 
                        description={description} 
                        growingZone={growingZone} 
                        grownFromSeed={grownFromSeed} 
                        heirloom={heirloom} 
                        idealTemp={idealTemp} 
                        imageURL={imageURL} 
                        plantingDate={plantingDate} 
                        scientificName={scientificName} 
                        seedDepth={seedDepth} 
                        soilType={soilType} 
                        spacing={spacing} 
                        sproutsIn={sproutsIn} 
                        sunlight={sunlight} 
                        timeToHarvest={timeToHarvest} 
                        watering={watering} />
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            ))}
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div >
    )
  }

  return <h1 className="text-white text-center mt-5 font-italic pt-5">~ Please Sign In ~</h1>
}

export default Garden;
```

My first time posting for help here, hopefully I provided enough info without being too long winded, and I really appreciate any help you might have for me! I'm stumped.

Thanks for your time. :)

Edit: Reducers:

```
import {
  GET_PLANTS,
  ADD_PLANT,
  DELETE_PLANT,
  PLANTS_LOADING
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  plants: [],
  loading: false
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PLANTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        plants: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case DELETE_PLANT:
      return {
        ...state,
        plants: state.plants.filter(plant => plant._id !== action.payload)
      };
    case ADD_PLANT:
      return {
        ...state,
        plants: [action.payload, ...state.plants]
      };
    case PLANTS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - This is surely not the answer you want, but as soon as I saw the word authentication in the first paragraph, I started to wonder. Would it be remotely possible (likely?) that such a feature would actual decrease appeal for your app? Logging-in is what I do with other people's stuff. If I've had an app written for me, why would I want to sign in? The least the author could have done is to alleviate that for me.

Comment: She's also a developer, and she isn't intended to always be the only user. Eventually I'd like to build a public API for plant growing specs, but my intent was to start with this as a gift to her since she loves gardening, I'm in between jobs, and studying programming. Thus, learning user authorization and Redux. Or at least trying to.  :)

Comment: Nice idea, but going a bit off-topic… make sure and have a backup gift ready, like some flowers, something romantic. Having a plan B when you're up against a deadline is never a bad idea.

Comment: Now for the on-topic. I agree with enhzflep, start simple. Authentication is often a sticky topic and can add be added later.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I haven't looked too much into your underlying issue, but regarding your comment about the "plants" console.log message logging twice is most likely due to your App component being wrapped in React.StrictMode. You can read more about that here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856#issuecomment-390206425

Comment: Lol, don't worry everyone, I do have backup gifts! I also have a version of the app deployed to heroku without user authentication, it stores its state pretty simply in react using hooks, but hey it works.

Problem is, with it deployed the way it is anyone can add/edit the one "garden" that exists, making it not very useful as a garden tracking app! Thus user authentication, and my current struggle.

Comment: localStorage.setItem("garden", JSON.stringify(state.plant.plants)) to write it out to localStorage would probably get you there.  It would be saved in her browser storage -- kind of like a local app.  Then when you want to load the garden just do let garden  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("garden")); Check out localStorage at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
This is the quickest easiest way and you can provide a way later to export the stored garden to other browsers.

Comment: Oh, I've already connected it to a MongoDB Atlas database and hosted it on Heroku. I'm just super new with Redux and so I'm probably making a stupid mistake with updating state, and that's why I have to refresh to get things to render. Maybe. Probably.